# replace the use of function declaration when using es6/es7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-2017

I prefer do function declaration

```
doSomething() //still works
function doSomething() {}
```

over

```
var doSomething = function() = {}
doSomething()
```

because with the function declaration, I don't have to worry about the order, it just got hoisted at the top. Now when it come to es6, my coworker like to do const doSomething = () => {} because for them they dislike the word 'function'. I lost the hoisting how can I fix it?

I hope I can do this

```
abc()
abc() => {}
```

but I have to use babel so that the word `function` can be ignore to make a function in es6/es7?

Comment: If you are targeting a browser or environtment that supports ES6, you won't need `babel`, so it depends.

Comment: Arrow functions are not hoisted. And it's actually a good behaviour since  it leas to more debuggable code.

Comment: Tell your coworker that you dislike `const`, or (arrow) function expressions. Make your coworker understand that `function` declarations are not "deprecated" in any sense in ES6+. Establish a coding convention together.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't:

```js
abc();
abc() => {console.log('test');}
```

Moreover, arrow functions do now have their own `this` context and cannot be used as constructors. Which means they are not only for people who do not want to use the `function` keyword.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: but we don't contructor that often, most of the time we just want to create function to 'store' business logic into smaller piece. I'm aware `this` is gone in arrow function, we find arrow function useful coz we write shorter code especially we don't have to explicitly return.

Comment: Then just use arrow functions. It is good practice in my opinion to declare your functions before using them anyways. So do not rely on hoisting.

Comment: ok make sense, there's no right or wrong thing, it's just preferences.